# get the reverse of a function for key producing

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, vb6

I'm tasked with making an online version (for automation purposes) of the app that produces the keys for a software.

each software shows the user an access code (from system volume information) and the key for that code is produced by a little app. so the client gives for example access code: 123 and he gets back the key: 321.

Now the problem is, the source of the little app that produces the key for this particular software is missing, but I do have the validation function

```
Public Function ValidateKey(AccessCode As Long, AccessKey As Long)

    Dim lngNewKey As Double
    Dim strHexKey As String
    Dim btCode(1) As Byte
    Dim lngCode As Long

    If AccessKey = 0 Then
        ValidateKey = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If AccessCode = 0 Then
        ValidateKey = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        lngNewKey = AccessKey
        strHexKey = Hex(lngNewKey)
        If Len(strHexKey) = 5 Then strHexKey = "0" & strHexKey
        btCode(0) = CByte("&H" & Mid(strHexKey, 1, 2))
        btCode(1) = CByte("&H" & Mid(strHexKey, 5, 2))
        lngCode = CLng(btCode(0)) * 256 + CLng(btCode(1))
        lngCode = lngCode * 15 + 5
        ValidateKey = (lngCode = AccessCode)
    End If

End Function
```

this function runs in the client software and checks whether the key provided by the user (AccessKey) was correct compared to the AccessCode.

So in order to find the key producing function I started reversing it by doing the following:

```
AccessCode = AccessCode - 5
AccessCode = AccessCode / 15
```

but then i got stucked, because the previous operation seems like a hash operation and seems difficult to reverse.

I have the following data ( by using the standalone key producing app ) :

```
for accesscode 111440 the key should be 1946629
for accesscode 200000 the key should be 3453973
for accesscode 65536 the key should be 1160209
for accesscode 8192 they key should be 177186
for accesscode 4096 they key should be 111633
```

the smallest accesscode it works with is 3838.

I was wondering if it's possible to derive the key producing function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you try access code 0?

Comment: 3838 is the smallest access code it works with, under that it gets a type mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It will not give the same access keys as in your examples (as you noticed, the reversing process is ambiguous), but it will give access keys that *pass the validation function*. C#, I don't know VB.

```
    static int Key(int accessCode)
    {
        accessCode = (accessCode - 5) / 15;
        return Int32.Parse(((accessCode >> 8) & 0xFF).ToString("X")
                          + "00"
                          + (accessCode & 0xFF).ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0'),              
                           System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
```

For example, your key pair is:

`(111440, 1946629)`

My function gives:

`(111440, 1900549)`

Both of which are validated successfully.

<strike>Edit: I see that the small numbers (65536 and below) in your examples don't validate successfully for me (neither with correct nor with calculated keys). Meaning I didn't correctly translate your validation function to C# (probably something to do with padding small numbers). Oh well. This may or may not mean the Key function doesn't work correctly for those values, I can't test it as my ValidateKey is incorrect.</strike>

Edit2: Actually the problem wasn't my translation, the problem is that your own ValidateKey function doesn't do what you say it does. I tested it in VB, direct copy-paste, and it returns:

1. 111440 1946629 -> True
2. 200000 3453973 -> True
3. 65536 1160209 -> False
4. 8192 177186 -> False
5. 4096 111633 -> False

***Edit3: The bug in your ValidateKey function is the following:***

```
    lngCode = lngCode * 15 + 5
    ValidateKey = (lngCode = AccessCode)
```

lngCode is `whole number * 15 + 5`. So it will always be a number that is divisible by 15 when 5 is subtracted. This means that *if accessCode - 5 isn't divisible by 15, ValidateKey will always return false!*

For example, if `accessCode` is `15000`, `ValidateKey` will return `false` no matter what `accessKey` is! Because there isn't an integer for which `i*15+5 = 15000` is true, it can never return `true`.

This is why it doesn't work for 65536 for example, not because you have the wrong key, but because it will always return false for code = 65536, regardless of key. It doesn't matter which key my function returns, ValidateKey will return false.

On the other hand, for a number like 6005 (6005 - 5 is divisible by 15), the key my function calculates will be validated successfully.

***Conclusion:***

You can generate keys for large enough N for which N-5 is divisible by 15 with my function.

For those numbers for which 15 doesn't divide N-5, it is not possible to generate the keys, as ValidateKey will never return true for them.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a function that will return compatible keys.

```
Public Function CreateKey(ByRef AccessCode As Long) As Long
    Dim tempcode As Long = CLng((AccessCode - 5) / 15)
    AccessCode = tempcode * 15 + 5
    Dim Hexout As String
    Hexout = Hex(tempcode / 256).PadLeft(2, "0"c) + "B4" + Hex(tempcode - (Math.Truncate(tempcode / 256) * 256)).PadLeft(2, "0"c)
    CreateKey = Convert.ToInt32(Hexout, 16)
End Function
```

By modifying AccessCode to be compatible with the key generated your validate function will always work.  Or you can make that a condition in the function that makes the accesscode.